# Visual Studio Controls Toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2008, which references a library that provides some custom user controls.

Is there any way for me to drag instances of the controls in this library onto forms that I am creating in the visual design view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[Add Custom Controls to the Visual Studio Toolbox](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSControlInToolbox.aspx)

[Adding Custom Controls to Visual Studio.Net Toolbox Programatically](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/addcontrol2toolbox.aspx)

Comment: These work, but the library containing the controls must have been created by VS as a "Form Control Library"